# CKEditor mentions - remove marker from feed

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

I have a feed with names which comes from my back-end as a First Last name. In the CKEditor feed the name is displayed as @First Last name. I was wondering how can I remove the @ from the feed and therefore from the exact mention when selected.

Example photo from CKEditor website

[image]

Comment: @Ogreucha that's not helpful, since the marker triggers the mention, so it should stay in the configuration file.

Comment: Maybe you have to define your own itemTemplate. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_plugins_mentions_configDefinition.html#property-itemTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was also struggling with this, because I was usinig an attribute called `name` in my feed data. This one seems to be occupied internally.
Changing to another attribute name resolved the problem for me:

`outputTemplate: "{firstname}"`:
shows the firstname attribute without the marker in the result.
`itemTemplate: "<li data-id="{id}">{firstname}</li>"`: shows the suggested matches without the marker as well.

Answer (score -1):

Managed to solve my problem by dividing the name from my back-end into first_name and last_name.

Comment: Can you give an example on how your item- and outputTemplate looks like?